# Calling a JavaScript function using a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to push through a PHP variable $getUserID to a JavaScript function that doesn't seem to accept it. I've been looking through a lot of answers on stackoverflow as well as the internet in general but I haven't found a solution yet.

Code:

PHP :

```
<!-- Comments Form -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
                    <form role="form" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="commentInput"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" onclick="checkComment(<?php echo $getUserID ?>)" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
var comment = {
    commentText: "",
    userID: ""
};

function setValues() {

    comment.commentText = document.getElementById("commentInput").value;

}

function validateComment(commentText) {

    if(!(commentText === "" || commentText.length < 1))
        return true;
}

function checkComment(userID) {

    setValues();
    alert(validateComment(comment.commentText));
    comment.userID = userID;
    alert(comment.userID);
    alert(comment.commentText);
}
```

What I'm trying to do, for testing purposes, is to print alert messages to see if every variable is received. No alert messages pop up when I hit the submit button. I believe it is an error due to the php variable. Is anyone able to spot the error?

Comment: Is your "userID" a number or a string? if a string you'll need quotes on it inside your inline event handler.

Comment: Look at the generated HTML / code and see if you generated valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" onclick="checkComment(<?php echo $getUserID ?>)" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

I wasn't using single quotations after "checkComment(".

Fixed code:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="checkComment(<?php echo $getUserID ?>')" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```